# Procedure and implicit cursore compilation error

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to check if the ceratin warehouse has full capacity.

**Here is how I tried to solve it:**

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
Create or Replace
Procedure Check_ein_Lager(lagernummer int) AS
summe int := 0;
capacityy int;
Begin
  for v_rec in (Select lager.stueckkap into capacityy from lager where lagernummer = lager.lnr) loop
    summe := summe + v_rec.stueck;
  if(summe<0)
  then DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Negativ'||' '||lagernummer||' '||summe);
  end if;
  if (summe > capacityy)
  then DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Höher'||' ' ||lagernummer||' '||summe);
  end if;
  end loop;
end Check_ein_Lager;
/

execute Check_ein_Lager(15);
```

I'm getting following error I've tried to debbuged it but no success.

```
Errors: check compiler log
Fehler beim Start in Zeile : 130 in Befehl -
execute Check_ein_Lager(15)
Fehlerbericht -
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00905: object IF4EBIHORACM.CHECK_EIN_LAGER is invalid
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
Procedure CHECK_EIN_LAGER kompiliert
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your tables have the expected columns, this should compile:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Check_ein_Lager (lagernummer INT)
AS
   summe        number := 0;
   kapazität    number;
BEGIN
   SELECT lager.stueckkap
     INTO kapazität
     FROM lager
    WHERE lagernummer = lager.lnr;

   FOR v_rec IN (SELECT *
                   FROM lagerbuchung
                  WHERE lagerbuchung.lnr = lagernummer)
   LOOP
      summe := summe + v_rec.stueck;

      IF (summe < 0)
      THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (
            'Negativ' || ' ' || lagernummer || ' ' || summe);
      END IF;

      IF (summe > kapazität)
      THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (
            'Höher' || ' ' || lagernummer || ' ' || summe);
      END IF;
   END LOOP;
END Check_ein_Lager;
```

Comment: In capacityy I want to store the current number of items from warehouse and then check e.g. for warehouse 15 the capacityy full is

Comment: I've solve it with an explicit cursor but I can't somehow with implicit ```set SERVEROUTPUT ON


cursor c1 is select *
from lagerbuchung
where lagerbuchung.lnr = lagernummer;
summe int := 0;
Begin
  Select lager.stueckkap
  into kapazität
  from lager
  where lagernummer = lager.lnr;
  
  for v_rec in c1 loop
  summe := summe + v_rec.stueck;
  if(summe<0)
  then DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Negativ'||' '||lagernummer||' '||summe);
  end if;
  if (summe >kapazität)
  then DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Höher'||' ' ||lagernummer||' '||summe);
  end if;
  end loop;
end Check_ein_Lager;
```

Comment: Posted an attempt, based on your working code with explicit cursor

Comment: Is it understandable based on second code here in comments ?

Comment: could you explain me and if possible show me how implicit cursor would look like ?

Comment: I can't get the point. An implicit cursor is what I just posted, something like `for ... in (select ...)`

Comment: I've tried following https://codeshare.io/5onmMZ but I still get compile error

Answer (score 0):

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE CHECK_EIN_LAGER(LAGERNUMMER INT) AS
SUMME INT := 0;
CAPACITYY INT;
CURSOR C_REC IS SELECT LAGER.STUECKKAP INTO CAPACITYY FROM LAGER WHERE LAGERNUMMER = LAGER.LNR;
BEGIN
  FOR V_REC IN C_REC LOOP
    SUMME := SUMME + V_REC.STUECK;
    IF(SUMME<0) THEN 
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Negativ'||' '||LAGERNUMMER||' '||SUMME);
    END IF;
    IF (SUMME > CAPACITYY)
      THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Höher'||' ' ||LAGERNUMMER||' '||SUMME);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END CHECK_EIN_LAGER;
/

EXECUTE CHECK_EIN_LAGER(15);
```